# Prevent input quanty from going negative in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a feature on my current site that increments and decrements a value when you click the plus button or the minus button. Since it's on an ecommerce site as an order quantity, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to have an option for the value to be negative. I was trying to add some logic to my jquery that would prevent the value from becoming negative but my nested logic wasn't working for some reason. Any help would be much appreciated!

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$('.up').on('click',function(){
            var num = $(this).parent().find('.input-quantity').val();
            $(this).parent().find('.input-quantity').val(parseInt(num)+1);
        });
        $('.down').on('click',function(){
              var num = $(this).parent().find('.input-quantity').val();
            $(this).parent().find('.input-quantity').val(parseInt(num) -1);
        }); 

});
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="quantity clearfix">
    <span>quantity:</span>  
           <div  class="incre">
        <em class="down">-</em ><input type="text"  value="1" class="input1 input-quantity "><em class="up">+</em ><br>

</div>  
      <div class="clear"></div>  

   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.quantity                        {margin: 30px 0 0 0;max-width:242px;border: solid 1px #d3d2d2;padding: 3px 0 6px 11px;border-radius: 4px;}
.quantity  span                 {display:inline-block;float:left;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 20px;padding: 6px 0 0 0;color: #333333;}
.incre                  {display:inline-block;float:right;margin: 0;width: 39%;}
.incre  em                  {display: inline-block;font-size: 26px;line-height: 31px;width: 29px;height: 29px;background: #cccccc;border-radius: 100%;color: #fff;padding: 0;float: left;text-align: center;margin: 0; cursor:pointer;}
.incre  .input1             {outline:none;border:0;display: inline-block;float: left;width: 20px;text-align: center;margin: 0 7px 0 3px;padding: 3px 0 0 0;font-size: 19px;height: 28px;line-height: 19px;color: #000;}
.quantity  small                {display:block;font-size: 18px;line-height: 20px;color: #000;padding: 0 12px 0 9px;}
```

**What I've tried:**

I've tried changing the functionality for the 'down' button in my jQuery to say that if the value equals zero when the function is executed, make the value equal to one and decrement the value. This hack would prevent the value from ever going negative.

```
    $('.down').on('click',function(){
          var num = $(this).parent().find('.input-quantity').val();
     if(num = 0){num = 1}
        $(this).parent().find('.input-quantity').val(parseInt(num) -1);
    });
```

I also tried:

```
if(num === "0"){num === "1"}
```

before the statement that decrements the value since it seemed like the integer may have been returning as a string.

Anyways, any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: you can use `<input type= 'number'>`

Comment: `<input type="number" min="0">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
if(num == 0) {
  num = 1;
}
```

instead of `num = 0`

Comment: This worked! Thanks. So why does the == vs. = make such a big difference?

Comment: Glad that it worked. In javascript, you compare values using `==` or `===` (`===` is for type checking, which you can use here as well - like `num === '0'`). You can read more at - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Answer (score 6):

Use an input `type=number`, then set a minimum

```
<input type="number" min="0">
```

Comment: Cool solution. My formatting got a little screwed up because it added arrows over the number. Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - but basically this gives you arrows too to increase and decrease so you shouldn't really need anything else

Comment: There's some specific design specs on this one. Is there a way to style the arrows or move them on either side of the number?